# Exception only shown on DEV env. symfony2

Tags: symfony, exception, http-status-code-404

I've got little problem.
I've overrided all html exception templates in app/Resources/TwigBundle/Resources/Exception...

My problem is, that these error pages are only rendered when I'm on the dev env.
When it comes to prod I'll get something like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHd7t.png

Please help me out.

Comment: defined/imported `/dupa2` route in  **routing_dev.yml** instead of **routing.yml**? cleared your cache ? `app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: Yes, I did it, but still the same. I managed to do the suggestion below and this worked for me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by registering a service listening to the kernel.view event.

in your service.yml:

```
your.kernel_listener:
    class: Your\AppBundle\EventListener\KernelListener
    arguments: [@kernel]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.view, method: onKernelView }
```

in your class KernelListener:

```
namespace Your\AppBundle\EventListener;    

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class KernelListener
{
    private $kernel;

    public function __construct(Kernel $kernel)
    {
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
    }        

    public function onKernelView(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {
        if ($this->kernel->getEnvironment() == 'dev') {
            $result = $event->getControllerResult();
            $response = new Response(print_r($result, true), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/html'));
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at [this guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-view-event).